# How to get previous row with certain parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pretty complicated question (At least for myself)
I have an SQL request that returns me the following table:

| ID | Date | Description | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 534 | 2021-01-01 4:03:14 | NEW | 1 |
| 534 | 2021-01-01 4:03:24 | Payment | 2 |
| 534 | 2021-01-01 4:04:14 | Accepted | 3 |
| 534 | 2021-01-01 4:05:23 | Support | 4 |
| 534 | 2021-01-01 4:05:32 | Cancelled | 5 |
| 632 | 2021-01-01 4:03:36 | NEW | 1 |
| 632 | 2021-01-01 4:04:12 | Payment | 2 |
| 632 | 2021-01-01 4:06:28 | Support | 3 |
| 632 | 2021-01-01 4:11:23 | Cancelled | 4 |
| 844 | 2021-01-01 5:03:36 | NEW | 1 |
| 844 | 2021-01-01 5:04:12 | Payment | 2 |
| 844 | 2021-01-01 5:06:28 | Accepted | 3 |
| 844 | 2021-01-01 5:11:23 | Cancelled | 4 |

What I need to do is to find those IDs that have **Description: Cancelled**, then get the previous description of the same ID.
But if previous **Description: Support** then I need to go to the next one.
To make it clear, here is the example of the output that I need:

| ID | Date | Description | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 534 | 2021-01-01 4:04:14 | Accepted | 3 |
| 632 | 2021-01-01 4:04:12 | Payment | 2 |
| 844 | 2021-01-01 5:06:28 | Accepted | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your table is named my_table and that by previous you mean item where rn equals rn - 1.

For the sake of simplicity I will not include the date column.

The key is to use the LAG() function of postgresql. Consider this query:

```
select 
    id, 
    description, 
    rn, 
    lag( description) over win as prev_desc, 
    lag( description, 2 ) over win as prev_desc2,
    lag(rn) over win as prev_rn, 
    lag(rn, 2) over win as prev_rn2
from my_table
window win as (partition by id order by rn)
order by id, rn
```

Here is its output:

```
id |description|rn|prev_desc|prev_desc2|prev_rn|prev_rn2|
---+-----------+--+---------+----------+-------+--------+
534|NEW        | 1|         |          |       |        |
534|Payment    | 2|NEW      |          |      1|        |
534|Accepted   | 3|Payment  |NEW       |      2|       1|
534|Support    | 4|Accepted |Payment   |      3|       2|
534|Cancelled  | 5|Support  |Accepted  |      4|       3|
632|NEW        | 1|         |          |       |        |
632|Payment    | 2|NEW      |          |      1|        |
632|Support    | 3|Payment  |NEW       |      2|       1|
632|Cancelled  | 4|Support  |Payment   |      3|       2|
844|NEW        | 1|         |          |       |        |
844|Payment    | 2|NEW      |          |      1|        |
844|Accepted   | 3|Payment  |NEW       |      2|       1|
844|Cancelled  | 4|Accepted |Payment   |      3|       2|
```

For each id, you see that you want the line where description = 'Cancelled' and either the value of prev_desc or prev_desc2 and prev_rn or prev_rn2.

Now we can use this query as a subquery:

```
select 
    id, 
    ( case prev_desc when 'Support' then prev_desc2 else prev_desc end ) actual_desc, 
    ( case prev_desc when 'Support' then prev_rn2 else prev_rn end ) actual_rn
from 
( select 
    id, 
    description, 
    rn, 
    lag( description) over win as prev_desc, 
    lag( description, 2 ) over win as prev_desc2,
    lag(rn) over win as prev_rn, 
    lag(rn, 2) over win as prev_rn2  
from my_table
window win as (partition by id order by rn)
order by id, rn ) subquery
where ( description='Cancelled' )
```

Its output is

```
id |actual_desc|actual_rn|
---+-----------+---------+
534|Accepted   |        3|
632|Payment    |        2|
844|Accepted   |        3|
```